# Visual Studio 2019 install MFC library?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I am inheriting a C++ code base on Windows in Visual Studio 2019 and I'm trying to compile the code, but it seems like VS cannot find the header files in the MFC library, e.g. "afxdialogex.h". I couldn't find any sources on the internet on how to install MFC and it seems like it should come with Visual Studio. Any ideas?

Disclaimer: I have zero Windows experience as I have exclusive used *nix systems until now.

Comment: If you do not have *any* Windows experience, you aren't going to understand MFC, at all. MFC is not a library that makes Windows programming easier. It is distinctly for Windows developers that know the system, to help them write safer code more efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/mfc-and-atl):

> In Visual Studio 2017 and later, MFC and ATL are optional sub-components under the **Desktop development with C++** workload in the Visual Studio Installer program. You can install ATL support without MFC, or combined MFC and ATL support (MFC depends on ATL). For more information about workloads and components, see [Install Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio).

You can either select MFC when [choosing workloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio#step-4---choose-workloads) (on the right-hand side), or [choose individual components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio#step-5---choose-individual-components-optional).

Comment: If it's an old code base, he might also want to install the MBCS options. It would be better to ensure everything is Unicode, but that might not be how the code is written or the effort they want to make.